# PSTricks figure too big

Tags: pdf, pstricks, paper-size

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
    \psgrid[gridcolor=red,subgridcolor=green,
      gridlabels=0](0,0)(5,5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(5.5,5.5)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I use `XeLaTeX` to compile, but when I look at the PDF it is not quadratic as I have said it should be in `pspicture`, but has dimensions 8.5 x 11in.

Why is that?

I am running texlive version 3.14... on ubuntu.

Comment: What does `quadratic` mean in this context?

Comment: @Bernard Same height and length

Comment: The class `article` uses a default page size of A4 or letter depending on your settings. The size of the `pspicture` indicates the size of the graphic and has nothing to do with the page size. You could use the `standalone` class to automatically make the page size the same size as the `pspicture`, or adjust page size in other ways.

Comment: I'm sorry, but with standalone class I have a perfect square 5cm × 5cm (1.97 × 1.97 in) with this code. I suppose there's something else. Btw, 8.5 × 11 in is `letter paper` format. Did you try to make an `.eps` file? Which version of XeLaTeX do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  a greater coordinate system for `pspicture`. With `\psframebox` you can make the area which TeX seas visible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psframebox*[fillcolor=black!20,fillstyle=solid]{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(5.5,5.5)%%%%%%%%%%
    \psgrid[gridcolor=red,subgridcolor=green,
      gridlabels=0](0,0)(5,5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(5.5,5.5)
  \end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want only the image as output use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

and run it with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or the sequence `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`